# django - TextField cannot be null or blank

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

This is my model:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True, null=True, default='')
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    of_type = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=TYPES)
```

When I `syncdb`, it does syncdb correctly. But when in the admin I try to save a blog without description, it does not. It shows error to

> This field is required.

How do I overcome this?

In the admin however I am using ckeditor to use its widget:

```
class BlogAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
    class Meta:
        model = Blog

class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BlogAdminForm

admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin)
```

Am I doing something wrong in the code? Please help me solve this. I will be very much grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the `required=False` argument to the form field definition:

```
description = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=CKEditorWidget())
```

BTW, you can use the [`formfield_overrides`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) option of the `ModelAdmin` instead of replacing the whole form:

```
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': CKEditorWidget()},
    }
```